# Disable all alarms on iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, alarm

I thought that switching the mute switch will disable all non-music sounds, but apparently that's not the case. Adjusting the music volume of course also didn't help. Is there a way to globally mute all sounds in iPhone? Or, is there a way to temporarily disable all alarms I have set? (example use case: I have alarms set for routines that are not applicable during travel)

Comment: You could use the Shortcuts App to create a Shortcut for disable (and one for re-enabling) your alarms. For more information, see: https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios

Comment: This also I find difficult. I just want to mute the whole phone in a lecture. Somehow, there are always exceptions and the iPhone will start screeching at exactly the wrong time. And there's nothing you can do to guarantee it won't do this except turn it off.

Comment: So this keeps the phone in a single app? That is good, but this also stops the use of the phone, so perhaps not too different from turning it off (though you can use a single app). Is there really no way to just disable to speakers? I sometimes just plug in headphones, that diverts all audio to the headphones. Perhaps there is a way to mimic this without headphones?

Comment: @apkg I don't think there is any other way other than ones that would require jailbreak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround. When `Guided Access` is turned on, all overlays and notifications are disabled, including all alarms. Refer to [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612) article if you want to learn more. The downside is that you have to exit and re-enter `Guided Access` every time you want to access control center or switch apps.

Answer (score 0):

Open Siri > say “Hey Siri" > “Cancel all my alarms” or “Turn off all my alarms” > If Siri says “I turned off all of your alarms”, you're all set.